# SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column LARAVEL 5.4

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

No puedo acceder a la relación con with desde la tabla padre a la hija, me dice:

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column
>   'subComidas.comida_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from
>   `subComidas` where `subComidas`.`comida_id` in (1, 2))

Lo raro es que reviso los modelos y están bien. De hecho, puedo llamar a la relación desde la tabla hija sin problemas u otras relaciones de comida.

Modelo tabla Comidas

```
class comida extends Model
{
protected $table = 'comidas';

protected $fillable = [
    'id',
    'cm_nombre',
    'created_at',
    'us_id',
    'updated_at'
];

// SUS HIJOS
public function planesAlimentarios(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('frust\planesAlimentario');
}

public function alimentos(){
  return $this->belongsToMany('frust\alimento');
}

public function subComida(){
    return $this->hasMany('frust\subComida');
}

// SUS PADRES
public function User(){
    return $this->belongsTo('frust\User','us_id','id');
}
}
```

Modelo taba hija:

```
class subComida extends Model

{
protected $table = 'subComidas';

protected $fillable = [
    'id',
    'sbc_nombre',
    'sbc_porcentaje',
    'created_at',
    'cm_id',
    'updated_at'
];
// SUS HIJOS
// SUS PADRES
    public function Comida(){
        return $this->belongsTo('frust\Comida','cm_id','id');
}
}
```

Como intento traer los objetos desde la tabla padre y me da error:

```
$comidas = comida::with(['subComida'])->paginate(5);        
    dd($comidas);
```

Como puedo intento traer los objetos desde la tabla hija (y los trae sin problemas)

```
$comidas = subComida::with(['Comida'])->paginate(5);        
    dd($comidas);
```

También intenté sobrescribir las llaves primarias con **$primaryKey**

Versión de laravel: 5.4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cuando defines la relación `subComida` en el modelo `comida`, puedes también especificar el campo de la llave foránea como segundo parámetro, y la llave local como tercer parámetro, en caso que estos dos no sigan los esquemas por defecto de Laravel, como es tu caso, específicamente con la llave foránea:

```
public function subComida(){
    return $this->hasMany('frust\subComida', 'cm_id');
}
```

Comment: Justo me habían indicado la respuesta, era lo mismo que tu. Muchísimas gracias!

Comment: Bueno, la otra respuesta lo indicó un poco más ambiguo, sin un ejemplo concreto que pueda ilustrar a quienes visiten esta pregunta en el futuro.

Answer (score 0):

En el modelo de la clase hijo específicas que el nombre de los ID no es el que laravel espera por defecto pero en el padre no lo especificas. Por ello trata de realizar la consulta con un campo que no existe.

Edita el modelo padre especificando el nombre correcto de la columna  id.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias! desconocía que igual debía especificar eso en la tabla padre